# How to launch JavaSparkContext client in cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark

How to launch JavaSparkContext client cluster mode? I'm trying to connect to the existing Spark cluster with cluster mode (Spark cluster workers don't have a network access to my machine where I run the Java code) with following configuration:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://spark-prod:7077")
                                    .setAppName("Word Count")
                                    .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster");
    // Create a Java version of the Spark Context
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

but the client ignores the setting and launches driver on my machine instead of using worker's one:

```
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 45847.
```

and worker executors are also trying to connect to my machine's driver and not one of the worker's driver (like it should be with spark.submit.deployMode property):

```
"--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@my_machine_dns:45847"
```

So here is a question: how to launch JavaSparkContext client in spark.submit.deployMode=cluster mode?

Comment: Are you running the main method directly on your machine? You should use `spark-submit` to run the driver on a remote cluster.

Comment: @ernest_k I am. I've tried to use spark-submit command and it worked perfectly. Am I unable to use a JavaSparkContext client with remote spark clusters?

Comment: You are **able** to do so, but the machine running your driver must be accessible from worker machines AFAIK

Comment: I thought with cluster mode communication is possible through open socket (and looks like it's working when I use spark-submit). Ok, thanks. I'll try to open a network access from Spark cluster to my machine.

Comment: Do you try to set the property `spark.driver.host` to force the driver to be on one of your worker ?

Comment: @Nonontb yeah, I've tried it - Spark can't bind a port on a remote IP (worker's one) and fails to launch.

Answer (score 0):

if you will able to do it with spark-submit command then you must able to do same using new JavaSparkContext(conf) ,here conf object should have mode as cluster
what i believe is that you need enable connection between your machine and cluster

Comment: I've double checked that spark-submit is working correctly with --deploy-mode cluster argument. JVM-client simply ignores similar property spark.submit.deployMode - I've posted messages from logs of a JVM-client and a worker's executor.